# Insert a link button in a Table

Tags: php, html

I am new to mysqli I think I have the basic's under me but I am battling to a button in a table that i can execute.

This is my code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr align='left'>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sysdate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['systime'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['controller'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sla_client'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" **BUTTON TO BE INSERTED HERE** "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

The below code obviously is not working in the above table

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = '../master.php';">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a button? Else you could use a normal `a`-tag. What is not working? Check in the console if you get an error.

Comment: you could make a form in your table

Comment: echo "<td><form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google" />
</form></td>"

Comment: @xmaster I don't think that's an appropriate solution the button should work.

Comment: @WasteD why not?

Comment: @xmaster Because its you are using a form as a button it will work thats for sure but it's not clean. I just tried your approach @Maggie and it worked for me the way you did it. So maybe is the path to the `master.php`-file wrong?

Comment: you could also use something like this `<a href="master.php"><button>Next</button></a>`

Comment: @xmaster That would be a much better solution :)

Comment: What exactly does "_is not working_" mean? Can't click it? Goes to a different url? Why don't you use a simple `<a href>` to change the url, like WasteD suggested?

Comment: @xmaster I used the form suggestion you gave echo "<td> <form action='../cases/dashboard.php'> <input type='submit' value='Go to Google' /> </form></td>"; and it worked

Comment: `echo "<td><a href=master.php><button>Click Here</button></a></td>";`

Answer (score 1):

#### You may find below solution:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
    <tr align='left'>
         <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['sysdate']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['systime']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['controller']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['sla_client']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['notes']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
         <td><a href="<?php echo $row['link of the BUTTON']; ?>">BUTTON text TO BE INSERTED HERE</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```

**Summary:**
Just don't put Too much HTML in PHP, it's bad practice.

Comment: Just don't forget to give a Star ;-) and Upvote if good answered good

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest: You could use something like this **with HTML "href" tag**.

Below is the Example of how to do it:

```sh
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   echo "<tr align='left'>";
      echo "<td>".$row['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['sysdate'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['systime'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['controller'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['sla_client'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['notes'] . "</td>";
      /* you could also use something like this with HTML href Tag */
      echo "<td><a href=master.php><button>Click Here</button></a></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```